# Webmatrix - including int's in my search page

Tags: list, razor, webmatrix

i have built a fully working search page for my WebMatrix property site. To summarize, it checks the query string, and if any of the defined values are present, it adds it to a list so it can iterate through them.

The problem, as you will see, if that it currently adds everything to the list as a string. This causes problems when i need to use the value as an INT (PropertyType and NumBedrooms should be int's). is there a way i can use both strings and int's in this scenario? can i add ints AND strings to the same list?

here's the code:

```
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var proptype = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Property_Type");

IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResults;

//Search Variables

string searchTerm = "";
string resortID = "";
string propertyType = "";
string numBedrooms = "";
List<string> argList = new List<string>();

//Paging Variables

var pageSize = 6; 
var totalPages = 0; 
var count = 0;
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

//Request querystrings from URL

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["searchTerm"]))
{
searchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"];
}

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["resortID"]))
{
resortID = Request.QueryString["resortID"];
}

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["propertyType"]))
{
propertyType = Request.QueryString["propertyType"];
}

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["numBedrooms"]))
{
numBedrooms = Request.QueryString["numBedrooms"];
}

int numOfArguments = 0;

string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Info ";

if (searchTerm != "")
{
argList.Add(searchTerm);
selectQueryString += "WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%' + @0 + '%' OR BriefDescription LIKE '%' + @0 + '%' ";

numOfArguments++; //increment numOfArguments by 1
}

if (resortID != "")
{
argList.Add(resortID);
if (numOfArguments == 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "WHERE ResortID = @0 ";
}
else
{
    selectQueryString += "AND ResortID = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
}
numOfArguments++;
}

if (propertyType != "")
{
argList.Add(propertyType);
if (numOfArguments == 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "WHERE PropertyTypeID = @0 ";
}
else
{
    selectQueryString += "AND PropertyTypeID = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
}
numOfArguments++;
}

if (numBedrooms != "")
{
argList.Add(numBedrooms);
if (numOfArguments == 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "WHERE NumBedrooms = @0 ";
}
else
{
    selectQueryString += "AND NumBedrooms = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
}
numOfArguments++;
}

selectQueryString += "ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC";

string[] argArray = argList.ToArray();

queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray);
count  = queryResults.Count();
totalPages = count/pageSize;        
if(count % pageSize > 0){
totalPages += 1;
}
```

Edited code after Polynomial's suggestion:

```
@{ 
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Search Page";

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var proptype = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Property_Type");

//Paging Variables

var pageSize = 6; 
var totalPages = 0; 
var count = 0;
var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResults;

//Request querystrings from URL

string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Info WHERE 0 = 0 AND NumBedrooms = @0 AND NumBathrooms = @1 ";

selectQueryString += "ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC";

queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, Request.QueryString["NumBedrooms"], Request.QueryString["NumBathrooms"]); 
count  = queryResults.Count();
totalPages = count/pageSize;        
if(count % pageSize > 0){
totalPages += 1;
}

}
```

Comment: Just to add, i have tried converting to an int by doing the following propertyType = Request.QueryString["propertyType"].AsInt() but it tells me that i cant implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are lots of ways around the problem, I'm thinking the easiest one that doesn't involve not using named ordinal parameterization would be to use fixed ordinals for each search criteria and just not use the ones you don't need in the SQL statement. Your code is very long so I don't really want to try and rewrite the whole thing here, but basically if your `db.Query()` call has all of the potential arguments passed as parameters like this:

```
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, Request.QueryString["searchTerm"], Request.QueryString["resortId"]).AsInt(), Request.QueryString["propertyType"].AsInt() /* etc etc */);
```

Then your ordinals are always the same number. `searchTerm` is always `@0`, `resortId` is always `@1` etc, etc. You then don't need the array at all and just need to build up an appropriate SQL statement for what the user specified, for example some `WHERE` clauses that would all fit with the code above could be:

```
"WHERE ResortID = @1"
"WHERE PropertyType = @2"
"WHERE ResortID = @1 AND PropertyType = @2"
"WHERE Name = @0"
"WHERE Name = @0 AND ResortID = @1 AND PropertyType = @2"
```

In the case of the clauses that only use one or two of the parameters, the others are just ignored and hopefully everything will work as you intend.

---

Edit to show code:

```
// Basic beginning of the select statement
string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Property_Info WHERE 0 = 0 ";

// Check to see if the user specified bedrooms, if they did add to the select statement
if (Request.QueryString["NumBedrooms"].AsInt() > 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "AND NumBedrooms = @0 ";
}

// Same for the number of bathrooms
if (Request.QueryString["NumBathrooms"].AsInt() > 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "AND NumBathrooms = @1 ";
}

// ** Add more criteria to your select list here by checking for valid values and concatenating your string **

// Finally add the order by on the end
selectQueryString += "ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC";

// Execute the statement
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, Request.QueryString["NumBedrooms"].AsInt(), Request.QueryString["NumBathrooms"].AsInt());
```

This should give you a very flexible and expandable search criteria system that is happy with zero, one or many criteria.

Comment: So is your suggestion to write a different query for each possible outcome, or one query that covers them all?

Comment: @Gavin5511 No, you would still build up your query depending on the values that the user enters - the key difference is that whereas at the moment your ordinals are numbered using your `numOfArguments` parameter and are therefore different for each set of criteria a user picks (i.e. in your current example `NumBedrooms` could end up as `@0`, `@1` or whatever depending on what the user picks), you should fix the ordinals for each parameter and supply them directly to the `db.Query()` call as in my answer. Sorry if it still isn't clear, it's quite a difficult concept to explain with just text.

Comment: nope, i get you! i'll spend a few hours putting your suggestion into practice. I was just concerned that the statement would break if it couldn't request the value from the query-string, ie if i had specified "WHERE ResortID = @1 AND PropertyType = @2" but i didn't have a value for ResortID in the string. But by the sounds of it, it'll just leave that out, so hopefully it'll work! i'll get back to you shortly dude. Thanks.

Comment: @Gavin5511 Yes, you can directly reference the request object even if they aren't set - if they are `null` then that will be the value that would end up in the SQL statement. It wouldn't produce correct results, but you won't be referencing them unless they are set so you should be all good regardless. Good luck!

Comment: @Gavin5511 Also, just to help you cut down on your logic a little, rather than having to check whether you are starting a `WHERE` clause or appending every time you can start your statement with any condition that is always true and then all of your code only has to deal with doing an `AND`. For example, if you start your statement as `SELECT * FROM Property_Info WHERE 0 = 0` then all of your string concatenation becomes vastly simplified.

Comment: ok, so i've made some changes above. It doesn't throw up any errors, but i ONLY get results if i specify both NumBedrooms AND NumBathrooms.Admittedly, if i can get it working this way, it is MUCH cleaner, but i need to be able to change the number of variables passed to querystrings. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: i can provide a live external link to this if needed.

Comment: @Gavin5511 You still need to concatenate the string based on what the user has actually input - you just use your fixed ordinals to do so. I'll edit my answer to explain directly what I mean using your edit in your question.

Comment: That works a treat! It's so less complicated than how i was doing it before. I'm just going to add a few more int, string and bool options, so check that it's happy with them all, and i'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Gavin5511 I think you have to manually award the bounty if I fixed your issue, otherwise the bounty gets wasted.